# Wieferich prime-Lang-Trotter conjecture connection?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Crandall-Dilcher-Pomerance prediction states that the number of Wieferich primes $<x$ is $log\ logx $
N.Katz in "WIEFERICH PAST AND FUTURE" states;

The Crandall-Dilcher-Pomerance prediction is analogous to the Lang-Trotter
conjecture [L-T] for an elliptic curve $E$ over $Q$.

So my question is; if it is proven that there are only 2 Wieferich primes base 2, does that mean the Lang-Trotter conjecture is false?

Comment: "Analogous" doesn't mean "equivalent".

Comment: Dupuy and Weirich, Bits of $3^n$ in binary, Wieferich primes and a conjecture of Erdos, available at http://www.math.ucla.edu/~dupuy/notes/erdos.pdf, write, "The distribution of Wieferich primes is the subject of the Lang-Trotter conjecture. A review of these facts can be found in [Lan90]." The reference is to Serge Lang, Old and new conjectured diophantine inequalities, Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, 23(1):37–75, 1990. Might be worth digging out the Lang paper, which should be freely available on the AMS site.

Answer (score -1):

I digged in the reference:The reference is to Serge Lang, Old and new conjectured diophantine inequalities, Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, 23(1):37–75, 1990.

On page 42 it is stated:

Actually, in line with Lang-Trotter conjectures, the probability
that $2^{p-1} = 1 + pk\pmod{p^2}$ with a fixed residue class $k \pmod p$
should be $O(1/p)$, so the number of primes $p\leq x$ such that
$2^{p-1} = 1 \pmod {p^2}$ should be $O(\log\log x)$.

So, I translate this as: "If there are only 2 Wieferich primes base 2, the Lang-Trotter conjecture is false". Any comments?

Comment: Even if the correspondence to Lang-Trotter were precise (which nothing in the article claims it is: note the phrase "should be", which is a moral equivalence and not a logical one), the fact remains that $2 \in O(\log \log x)$ so there is no literal contradiction.  The context of the argument is getting an upper bound on the number of Wieferich primes, not an asymptotic estimate.